# A bounded integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I want to show that there exists $K\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that
$$\left|\int_{1}^x \sin(t+t^7)dt \right|<K$$
for all $x\ge 1$. Intuitively, I'm quite sure it is true, but I can't find a formal proof. Any idea?

Comment: It would take a long time to write a good argument, but you can argue that for all $x$, this is smaller than the partial sum of an alternating series with the terms equal to the integral between roots of the sine function.  Argue that the series converges by the Alternating Series test.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = x + x^7$, and $g(t)$ its inverse function on $[0,\infty)$.
Then $$\int_0^x \sin(x + x^7)\ dx = \int_0^{f(x)} \sin(t) g'(t)\ dt$$
It can be shown that as $t \to \infty$, 
$$g(t) = t^{1/7} - \dfrac{1}{7} t^{-5/7} + O(t^{-11/7})$$
and 
$$g'(t) = \dfrac{1}{7 g(t)^6 + 1} =  \dfrac{1}{7} t^{-6/7} + O(t^{-12/7})$$

Now $\int_1^\infty |\sin(t)| t^{-12/7}\ dt < \infty$.
On the other hand, using Integration by Parts,
$$ \int_1^R \sin(t) t^{-6/7}\ dt = \left. - \cos(t) t^{-6/7} \right|_1^R - 
\dfrac{6}{7} \int_1^R \cos(t) t^{-13/7}\ dt$$ 
and again the term on the right is bounded.